# Access assigning Null / Default value

Tags: vba, ms-access, null, default

I have a form in Access with several comboboxes.

If the user selects X in combobox A a value is assigned to another field (Field A). This is working fine now (through VBA code in the on change event).

However, if the user selects Y in combobox A I would like the value in Field A to return its default value (empty/null).

Currently I have it returning to 0, but that is not ideal. What can I do to make it return to default/null/empty?

I tried:

Field A = Null

**But then I get the following message:**

*You tried to assign the Null value to a variable that is not a Variant data type. (Error 3162)*

When I make it Field A = 0 then it is working, but as I said before that is not ideal for my situation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about an empty string?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.

However, when I try Field A = " " or Field A = ""

Then I get following error message: The value you entered is not valid for this field.

The field I am referring to is integer field if it matters.

Comment: The thing is the error message refers to a variable, not a control, so there is not enough information here. Fields belong to tables, not forms. You have not said if the control is bound or unbound.

Comment: I don't know Access object model, so just suggesting if there's some "Clear" method to use on Fields

Comment: Hi Fionnuala, thank you for your comment. Your right I did not provide enough info. The form is a bound form. Basicly I just want to clear the form control, so the user is forced to think him or herself.